# Ruby on Rails: Cucumber: how to verify javascript alert text?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cucumber

So, my app has a javascript alert... how do I, using cucumber and / or capybara, test that the alert hay a particular string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Cucumber + Webrat + Selenium. You can then write statements like

```
selenium.is_alert_present.should be_true
selenium.get_alert.should eql("File Deleted")
```

:-)

Comment: is there a way to do this with culerity? selenium errors the balls out of itsself on my machine